How to fix a basic display problem for my responsive design?
I am writing a page right now as a project and I am trying to make it responsive but however something in my code makes the "social_links" stick to left after 560px screen width but it has to stay in center just like it stays when width is not narrow. I have deleted parts that are not about my problem since it is already long.


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.container {
  width: 30em;
  margin: 4em;
}

.social__links ul li {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1.2rem 0;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.8rem;
  perspective: 500px;
  user-select: none;
}

.js-tilt-glare {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.social__links ul li a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.social__links ul li a i {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4rem;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  transform: scale(1.4) translateZ(50px);
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.social__links ul li a span {
  line-height: 1.4rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 549px) {
  .container {
    width: 88vw;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1158px) {
  .navbar .links {
    display: none;
  }
  .navbar .toggle {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown_menu {
    display: block;
  }
  .msg {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  #br {
    width: 35%;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 576px) {
  .social__links p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .social__links ul li {
    padding: 0.3rem 0.6rem;
  }
  .social__links ul li a i {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 3rem;
    padding: 8px 16px;
  }
  .social__links ul li a span {
    font-size: 0.9rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .social__links ul li {
    padding: 0.2rem 0.4rem;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    padding: 0.2rem 0.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .social__links ul li a i {
    line-height: 2.4rem;
    padding: 6px 12px;
  }
  .social__links {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .social__links ul {
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .social__links ul li a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}

.social__links p {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .social__links ul li a h3 {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
  .social__links ul li a p {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-SnH5WK+bZxgPHs44uWIX+LLJAJ9/2PkPKZ5QiAj6Ta86w+fsb2TkcmfRyVX3pBnMFcV7oQPJkl9QevSCWr3W6A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="social__links">
    <ul id="item">

      <li class="instagram">
        <a href="..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-instagram fa-2xl"></i>
          <span>
              <h3>...</h3>
              <p>...</p>
            </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="mail">
        <a href="..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
          <span>
              <h3>...</h3>
              <p>...</p>
            </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="youtube">
        <a href="..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-x-twitter fa-lg"></i>
          <span>
          <h3>...</h3>
          <p>...</p>
        </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="discord">
        <a href="..." target="_blank">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-globe fa-lg"></i>
          <span>
            <h3>...</h3>
            <p>...</p>
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>




Looks like it is the fault of the container class, which sets width: 30em ...?
